# Is multicast appropriate for one to many streaming within a localhost?

Tags: python, sockets, multicast

I have a central data feed that I want to redistribute to many clients. The data feed produces approx. 1.8 kB/s.  Currently I'm writing the feed to a file and each client reads off the end of the file. Something about this just seems wrong. Here is pseudo code for what I have now...

The feed:

```
o = open('feed.txt','a',0) #no buffering, maybe line buffer would be better
while 1:
    data = feed.read(8192)
    data = parse_data(data)
    o.write(data)
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

The server (each client connects in a new thread):

```
feed = open('feed.txt','r')
feed.seek(-1024,2)
while 1:
   dat = feed.read(1024)
   if len(dat)==0:
       # For some reason if the end of the file is reached
       # i can't read any more data, even there is more.
       # some how backing off seems to fix the problem.
       self.feed.seek(-1024,2)
       self.feed.read(1024)
   buffer += dat
   idx = buffer.rfind('\n')
   if idx>0:
       data = buffer[:idx]
       buffer = buffer[idx+1:]
       for msg in data.split('\n'):
           client.send(msg)
   time.sleep(0.01)
```

What I'd like to do is just replace the file with a socket and write the messages directly to multicast packets.  Any time a new client connects to the server I just spin up a new thread and start listening for the multicast packets.  Are there any standard design patterns to handle this case?

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler, just have all clients multicast on the same port.  Then your server doesn't even need to track pseudo-connections.

We use a similar scheme for some of the software on our internal network, based on the fact that multicasting is "mostly reliable" on our networking infrastructure.  We've stress tested the load and don't start dropping packets until there's over 30K messages/sec.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import socket

ADDR = "239.239.239.9"
PORT = 7999

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((ADDR,PORT))
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(2048)
    print data
    sys.stdout.flush()
```